# Deserialization JSON unknown type

Tags: java, json, serialization

In my project, I'm facing to a problem of JSON serialization. I have made a quick simple example to illustrate it:

I have created an object Session which contains a hashMap.

```
public class session {

    private Map<String, Object> mapKeyValue = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Object> getMapKeyValue() {
        return mapKeyValue;
    }

    public void setMapKeyValue(Map<String, Object> mapKeyValue) {
        this.mapKeyValue = mapKeyValue;
    }
}
```

This map can contains various object. I only know the type of these objects at runtime. Example :

```
public class Dog {
    private final String race;
    private final String name;

    public Dog(String race, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.race = race;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRace() {
        return race;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Insect {
    private final int nbPates;
    private final String name;

    public Insect(int nbPates, String name) {
        this.nbPates = nbPates;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNbPates() {
        return nbPates;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I want to save my object session to a database to be able to restore it later.

My first idea was to serialize my session object in json and then to save to to database.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final session session = new session();
        session.add("Dog", new Dog("labrador", "milou"));
        session.add("Insect", new Insect(4, "cafar"));

        String output = serializeJSON(session);
        final session session2 = (session) deserializeJSON(output, session.class);
        Dog dog = (Dog)session2.get("Dog");

}
```

It works well. When i deserialize it, there is no error, but as a result, the map contained in the deserialized Session doesn't contain the original type of object but contains hashMap$Node objects.

I guess the deserialization can not guess the types of objects from the string.

Is there a workAround or any other strategy to save my session to database and to be able to restore it as it was previously ?

Comment: Try using Jackson or Gson, or any other actual JSON serialization library

Comment: Actually, I m using Gson

Comment: Then your Session object should not be necessary

Comment: Sorry can you develop ? I guess it would be the same if you would like to deserialize directly the map. Many thanks

Comment: A `TreeMap<String, Object>` is all you're going to get... You have to manually cast to your individual object classes. Maybe you want generic types? https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#serializing-and-deserializing-generic-types